# Scopebar hide / show UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift3, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

I want to have a button that hides and shows the scope bar.  Seems simple.  But It only works before an actual search.  After searching the animation happens to show the search bar, but it isn't there.  Any suggestions?  NOTE: I am using the bookmark button with my own custom image to show / hide the scopebar.

[Video of Issue Here](https://youtu.be/aimgExNMfz8)

```
func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
   DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

    self.isFilter = self.isFilter ? false : true
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = self.isFilter ? ["First Name", "Last Name", "Unit"] : nil

    self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = self.isFilter

    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(0..<1), with: .automatic)
    })

 }
```

I also have this in updateSearchResults:

```
    if searchController.isActive {
        searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = false
    } else {
        searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = true
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `showsScopeBar` somewhere in other functions. If yes, can you please post the code how you are using.

Comment: No just in the code above.  isFilter is originally set to false.  Also, NOTE: I have put in a bug with Apple for this, because it works the first time through, just not subsequent times.